# python minidom parser returns incomplete text value

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am trying to update the existing XML file. If the tag is not present in the XML file, the code should add it else do nothing. So, there is a method to find whether the Node is already present or not, based on the node name value.

```python
def findElementNodeByName(parentNode, elementTagName, nameValue):
    elementNodes = parentNode.getElementsByTagName(elementTagName)
    if not elementNodes:
        return None
    for elementNode in elementNodes:
        if elementNode.getElementsByTagName("Name"):
            if elementNode.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeType == xml.dom.Node.TEXT_NODE and \
               elementNode.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].data == nameValue:
                return elementNode
        else:
            raise Exception("Tag not found." )
    return None
```

The XML node will be something like,

```
<DC>
  <ESX>
    <Name>abcd.xyz.com</Name>
    <pnic>vmnic3</pnic>
  </ESX>
  <ESX>
    <Name>efgh.xyz.com</Name>
    <pnic>vmnic2</pnic>
  </ESX>
</DC>
```

So, when I try to add node ESX abcd.xyz.com, `findElementNodeByName` should return the existing node. But few times `findElementNodeByName` method returns None for existing nodes. This is a inconsistent issue.

While debugging, I figured out the parser returns partial value for text node, for example,  `elementNode.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].data` gives `abcd.x` instead of `abcd.xyz.com`.